# How can I apply analysers to a specific field in elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, kibana

I have a movies dataset and It has a field named as title ,now I want to set mappings with some search analysers,how can I do that

Expecting successful search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**so first of all you have to set your mappings before inserting data with some analyzers,**

[image]

look at the image, we have created a mapping on the field title,
Now we can bulk post data of movies (which has a field of title in it)

like this,
[image]